# WPF, rendering a million polygons, nVidia Quardro K2200

Tags: wpf, rendering, gpu, nvidia, polygons

I need to display more than a million polygons on a usercontrol to display CAD inquiry. Because I need to be able to zoom in to view the polygons, they can't be drawn onto a bitmap. So in the OnRender override, I use StreamGeometry, StreamGeometryContext to generate polygon geometry. I was surprised how little WPF takes advantages of the powerful nVidia GPU. On the nVidia Control Panel, Workstation, Manage GPU Utilization, I can monitor how many % the GPU has been tapped. During rendering, it routinely uses less than 30% during the OnRender call. After the end of the OnRender, no GPU has been use and the CPU is still clunking away data in the background trying to display. After the polygons are drawn, it becomes impossible to scroll (the control is in a ScrollViewer), change opacity, etc. These operations do not tap into any of the GPU resources either. My only solution so far is set the usercontrol's CacheMode = new BitmapCache(8).

How can I let WPF uses the GPU in this case?

```
                        for (int j = 0; j < Data.Count; j++)
                    {
                        StreamGeometry geometry = new StreamGeometry();
                        geometry.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;
                        using (StreamGeometryContext context = geometry.Open())
                        {
                            ...
                            {
                                Point startPoint = new Point(aPolygon[0].X, aPolygon[0].Y);

                                List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
                                //draw polygons
                                bool isPolygonViewAble = false;
                                if (viewingRect.Contains(startPoint)) isPolygonViewAble = true;
                                for (int i = 1; i < aPolygon.Count; i++) //foreach (CADGlobal.aPoint pt in polygon)
                                {
                                    Point apoint = new Point(aPolygon[i].X, aPolygon[i].Y);
                                    if (viewingRect.Contains(apoint)) isPolygonViewAble = true;
                                    points.Add(apoint);
                                }
                                if (isPolygonViewAble)
                                {
                                    context.BeginFigure(startPoint, true, true);
                                    context.PolyLineTo(points, true, false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        geometry.Freeze();
                        dc.DrawGeometry(null, pen, geometry); //place null with a brush to fill
```

Comment: According to MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196(v=vs.110).aspx), it can be roughly said that usage of GPU depends on the version of DirectX. What's your DirectX version?

Comment: I have DirectX 11 on my Windows 7 64bits system. RenderCapability.Tier>>16 returns 2.